# Visit Rome city while my 6 hours layover at Rome before leaving for Malta

Tags: visas, schengen, layovers, italy, rome

I needed to travel to Malta on a business trip. Since there was no Maltese Embassy in my country so I applied through Italian Consulate (on behalf of Malta) for the Schengen visa. This was the first time I applied for Schengen visa and fortunately I got it approved and my itinerary is as follows (no changes in itinerary before applying and after getting the visa):

I am traveling via Turkish airline and my itinerary is as follows:

- my country to Istanbul (3 hours stay) - via Turkish Airline
- Istanbul to Rome (Italy) (6 hours stay) - via Turkish Airline
- Rome to Malta - via Air Malta

So, my question is:

- Since I've 6 hours long stay in Rome (that is a Schengen state too) is it legal to go out and see the city ? For instance, visit the nearby locations like Colosseum etc !?
- If Yes, am I breaking some rules by going out of the airport and seeing the city, because initially I was given business Visa to visit Malta ?

Again, this is the first time I am traveling to Europe.

**Edit:**

No this is not the possible duplicate, because:

- I've single entry Schengen visa for a month
- I applied for business visa for Malta, but I'm going out in Rome while my layover

Thanks

Comment: You can leave the airport and visit Rome. You will already clear immigration there anyway!

Comment: that means there wont be any immigration checks at Malta airport? I mean the entry stamp ?

Comment: No, because you are already in Schengen. There will only be customs at Malta.

Comment: Well, I've updated my question. My scenario is different then the linked question.

Comment: The answer is still the same.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get your point.. Buying entry ticket in advance for what ?

Comment: With only six hours in Rome I wouldn't bother doing that unless you want to take a taxi for two hours to drive you from the Colosseum and back (which might easily cost 100€).

Comment: Thanks all. I landed Rome yesterday and went outside airport. I hired a cab (Van) of total 120 euros. I went to Colosseum, some fountain and a cathedral